# Is there any way to publish pyarmor obfuscated python package which is python version independent?

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging, pyarmor

So I am trying to publish a proprietary python package and I am using `pyarmor` package to obfuscate it and then publish the obfuscated build on `PyPi`. It is working on the same python version environment, however as mentioned in the [packaging-obfuscated-scripts](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/getting-started.html#packaging-obfuscated-scripts) it is version dependent and can not not be ran using any older or newer python version.

I have quite a heavy package, is there any way around this (avoiding building and maintaining package with different python version)?

EDIT: If not as mentioned in the documentation, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: No, CPython extension modules only work with the interpreter ABI they're compiled for. That's explicitly mention in the documentation page you linked

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.

Under the hood, `pyarmor` creates a [CPython extension module](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-extension-module) inside the "obfuscated" package. Extension modules are tied to a specific [interpreter ABI](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html#c-api-stability), and need to be compiled separately for different minor releases of CPython (i.e., 3.10, 3.11, 3.12, etc.).

This is mentioned in the [documentation linked in the question](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/getting-started.html#something-need-to-know):

> "when obfuscating scripts by Python 3.8, they can’t be run by Python 3.7, 3.9 etc."

As far as "avoiding building and maintaining package with different python version", this usually isn't a problem in practice. It's straightforward to build and publish wheels for multiple Python versions from a CI/CD workflow like GitHub Actions. PyPI even provides first-class support for doing so. See [Publishing package distribution releases using GitHub Actions CI/CD workflows](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/publishing-package-distribution-releases-using-github-actions-ci-cd-workflows/) from the Python Packaging docs for an example of how this is done with GitHub. You can adapt the same principles to whatever CI/CD platform you use.